# Excel Exports Extra Commas to CSV

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a large macro program run through Excel 2010 that, after formatting large amounts of data into another table and exporting the workbook as a CSV file (by large amounts of data I mean thousands of rows, up to over 59,000 rows). Recently, my files have started ending up with an extra row of commas at the end like so:

```
data,data,data,data,number,date
data,data,data,data,number,date
,,,,,
```

I am exporting these files to an SQL database using a stored procedure, so ensuring that there are no extra commas to screw with the program is essential. So, with that said, what is happening and how can I prevent it? I can provide any code or information that you believe is missing.

NOTE: It only appears to be happening on files with a couple thousand lines at least of data. One file exported often has 2,000+ and another must have 59,000+ for the table to be exported.

EDIT1: Here's the macro I'm using, just in case it would be helpful (requested by Ditto)

```
Sub exportTable()
Dim varIsOpen As Boolean
Dim varSaveLocation1 As String, varSaveLocation2 As String
varIsOpen = False

If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("D2").value = "" Then
    varSaveLocation1 = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\CSVREVIEW\"
    varSaveLocation2 = varSaveLocation1 & Year(Now) & Month(Now) & Day(Now) & Hour(Now) & Minute(Now)
Else
    varSaveLocation1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ControlSheet").Range("D2").value
    If Right(varSaveLocation1, 1) <> "\" Then varSaveLocation1 = varSaveLocation1 & "\"
    varSaveLocation2 = varSaveLocation1 & Year(Now) & Month(Now) & Day(Now) & Hour(Now) & Minute(Now)
End If
    For counter = 1 To Workbooks.Count
        If Workbooks(counter).Name = "TableBook.xls" Then varIsOpen = True

        If varIsOpen = True Then Exit For
    Next

    If varIsOpen = False Then GoTo isClosed

Workbooks("TableBook").Activate

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

'Check if TableBook is empty and don't export if so
If Workbooks("TableBook").Sheets("logFile").Range("A1").value = "" Then
    Workbooks("TableBook").Close
    GoTo isClosed
End If

'On Error Resume Next
If Len(Dir(varSaveLocation1, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
   MkDir varSaveLocation1
End If
If Len(Dir(varSaveLocation2, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then
    MkDir varSaveLocation2
End If
'On Error GoTo 0

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("test").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs varSaveLocation2 + "\test", xlCSV

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("part").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs varSaveLocation2 + "\part", xlCSV

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("logFile").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs varSaveLocation2 + "\logFile", xlCSV

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("deltaLimits").Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs varSaveLocation2 + "\deltaLimits", xlCSV

ActiveWorkbook.Close

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

isClosed:
End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely you have a blank cell or something "used" after the last row of data.  I can duplicate this in a small spreadsheet with a few rows of data, then cursor down 2 rows, and hit "<SPACE>+<ENTER>" (ie blank cell). then export csv - viola, extra comas. Could be something else, however, you'll probably want to start by making sure anything below your data is deleted. (ie delete rows or something).

Comment: I'll run the program again and see if that's the case. I should have an update in about 10 minutes. Thanks for the suggestion, @Ditto

Comment: @Ditto I stopped the program at the point where there would be an opportunity to experience what you're describing, but if there was an "empty cell" by your standards, I would be able to go up to the formula bar and highlight the space in that cell. There's no space in the last row of the one I'm exporting. I'll try clearing that last row before exporting, although I'm not sure how much it'll help.

Comment: What highlights if you hit <CTRL>+<A> ? Try doing a COUNTA() on each column ... see if that number "makes sense". Ie if you have 100 rows of (nonblank) data, it shouldn't come back with 101 ;) Outside of that, not sure .. don't suppose you could post your macro ?

Comment: Tap `Ctrl+End` to see what Excel believes is the extents of you r data. If it is beyond what you want to export, clear all from the rows below and the columns to the right of your desired data region and save the workbook. Excel 2010 (with all SPs) will adjust to the *CurrentRegion*. Earlier versions may require additional steps.

Comment: Thank you, @Jeeped! That did work. If you would like to post that as an answer I would be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> to see what Excel believes are the extents of your data. If it is beyond what you want to export, use Home ► Editing ► Clear ► Clear All to wipe all values and formatting from the rows below and the columns to the right of your desired data region and save the workbook. Excel 2010 (with all SPs) will adjust to the CurrentRegion and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> should now take you to the correct *last cell*.

Earlier versions of Excel (or XL2010 without all SPs) may require additional steps (see [Unwanted extra blank pages in Excel](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/unwanted-extra-blank-pages-in-excel-2010/3b9783b5-2ace-4582-9b92-b8c83c074369)).

Comment: For future reference: VBA code to do this was accomplished through using the `.Clear` command on the `.EntireRow` of one row after `Range("A1").End(xlDown)`.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue which looked the same (extra commas in csv) and it turned out that I was exporting one extra line in my loop and the cells I was using were empty, therefore I got commas only

Answer (score 0):

I had the exactly same problem. If the entire sheet is formatted, even just Text type or Text Height, Excel detects even empty cells as data. You can delete the entire formatted columns/ rows as described above [Cœur](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28415554/12106141). Or just create a new sheet without formatting anything and copy your code or change the address.